# How to get value out of custom html tags from DOMDocument or file_get_content

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can get value out of custom HTML tags in PHP form URL, for example:

```html
<key>1234</key>
```

I've tried like that:

```
    $html = file_get_html("https://example.com");
    foreach($html->find('key') as $element) {
         echo $element;
    }
```

And like that:

```
    $site = file_get_contents("https://example.com");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($site, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $data = $dom->getElementsByTagName("key");
    $html = $dom->saveHTML($data);
    echo $html;
```

But without result. ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the text inside an element, you have to use something like: this.

```
$html = file_get_html("http://randomurl.com");

// First element
$element = $html->find("key",0); // The first <key> element
$text = $element->plaintext; // The text

// Mutilple elements
foreach($html->find("key") as $element){
    print($element->plaintext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `strip_tags($html)` to remove the HTML tags?